# Scala DSL "and" keyword for chaining multiple commands

Tags: scala, dsl

Say I have two objects `A` and `B` of same type with methods `doX` and `doY`, both of which return boolean values.

Is it possible to create a language construct such as `and` or `or` which would perform the following?

> A doX and doY B

Normally the above would be accomplished with

> A doX B && A doY B

And I was wondering if this could be shortened as above

I would want `and` to be generalized for multiple methods, not just specifically `doA`, so I couldn't make it work with implicit alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala parser translates

```
A doX and doY B
```

to

```
A.doX(and).doY(B)
```

before any definitions, type information, etc. are considered, so you can't affect this translation in any way.

However you define `and`, `A.doX(and)` will return `Boolean` (if it compiles) and won't have `doY` method. You can make it type-check with implicit conversion

```
implicit def wrap(x: Boolean): A.type = A
```

but this still doesn't get the desired result.

I don't think making `and` a macro helps either, but it's possible I'm overlooking something there.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out the syntax might not be entirely impossible, but this is still pretty ugly. Especially requires some heavy modification to your `A` class. But here's a proof of concept:

```
case class Bar(s: String)

trait PredicateArgumentContext[-T] {
  type Result
  def apply(f: Foo, p: Bar => Boolean, arg: T): Result
}

implicit val ApplyPredicateArgumentContext = new PredicateArgumentContext[Bar] {
  type Result = Boolean
  def apply(f: Foo, p: Bar => Boolean, arg: Bar): Boolean = p(arg)
}

sealed trait PredicateOperator

object and extends PredicateOperator
object or extends PredicateOperator

implicit val OperatorPredicateArgumentContext = new PredicateArgumentContext[PredicateOperator] {
  type Result = Foo
  def apply(f: Foo, p: Bar => Boolean, arg: PredicateOperator): Foo = arg match {
    case `and` => f.copy(predTransform = (p1 => b => p(b) && p1(b) ))
    case `or` => f.copy(predTransform = (p1 => b => p(b) || p1(b) ))
  }
}

case class Foo(predTransform: (Bar => Boolean) => (Bar => Boolean) = identity) {

  def doX[A](a: A)(implicit ctx: PredicateArgumentContext[A]): ctx.Result = {
    ctx.apply(this, predTransform(doXInternal _), a)
  }
  def doY[A](a: A)(implicit ctx: PredicateArgumentContext[A]): ctx.Result = {
    ctx.apply(this, predTransform(doYInternal _), a)
  }

  def doXInternal(b: Bar): Boolean = {
    b.s.size % 2 == 0
  }

  def doYInternal(b: Bar): Boolean = {
    b.s.size > 0
  }
}

val A = Foo()
val B = new Bar("asdf")

A doX and doY B // returns true
```

They key insight is to get scala to parse it as `A.doX(and).doY(B)` and have the `doX` and `doY` methods return different types if passed an operator (`and` or `or`) or if passed an actual argument (`B`).